# Checkstyle's PackageHtml-rule ignores package-info.java

Tags: xml, javadoc, checkstyle

I use checkstyle to analyze my code. A useful rule is PackageHtml, that checks, if a package contains a Javadoc-description. But with newer java-version it's recommended to use package-info.java instead of package.html. Problem is, checkstyle ignores the package-info.java and reports a rule violation. How can checkstyle be configured to check for package-documentation, but accepts package.html **and** package-info.java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of CheckStyle are you using ?

It seems to be an [old bug](http://myt.ag/URLWeb.aspx?email=steve%40fooworks.com&url=https%3a%2f%2fsourceforge.net%2ftracker%2f%3ffunc%3ddetail%26atid%3d397078%26aid%3d1228207%26group_id%3d29721&sn=) closed late 2007.

Actually, the documentation mentions package-info as [being the default](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html)!... 
but only with CheckStyle 5.x, not 4.4

The announce for CheckStyle5.0 beta1 [is here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=488F8212.2020106%40koedderitzsch.net&forum_name=checkstyle-announce).
CheckStyle 4.4 is the last one compatible with jdk1.4

Comment: I use the stable version. You say that this works in the upcoming release? That would be cool. Then I can't wait for the new version.

Comment: Yes, the checkstyle 5.5 is more JDK5 or JDK6 oriented, but I believe you can use it right now.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. As I don't want rely too much on beta-version, I hope they will move fast to the final release.

Comment: Thank you for this positive feedback. I will update this post as soon as checkstyle 5.0 will be officially released.